Can't get the Phoenix.LiveComponent example to work
I'm following the official documentation on how to build a LiveComponent.
I get this error which I don't understand why:
I get this error when I load /cameras:
[error] GenServer #PID<0.864.0> terminating
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function MyAppWeb.HeroComponent.__live__/0 is undefined (module MyAppWeb.HeroComponent is not available)

I've created lib/my_app_web/components/hero.exs
defmodule MyAppWeb.HeroComponent do
  use MyAppWeb, :live_component

  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <div class="hero"><%= @content %></div>
    """
  end

In lib/my_app_web/live/camera_live/index.ex I add an alias:
defmodule MyAppWeb.CameraLive.Index do
  use MyAppWeb, :live_view

  alias MyApp.Cameras
  alias MyApp.Cameras.Camera
  alias MyAppWeb.HeroComponent # Added this

And I updated camera_live/index.html.heex by adding this line:
  <.live_component module={HeroComponent} id="hero" content={"random data"} />

The routes:
mix phx.routes | ack cameras
  GET   /cameras                                    MyAppWeb.CameraLive.Index :index

I'm using Phoenix 1.7.11 and Phoenix LiveView 0.20.2

I had mistakenly named the LiveComponent hero.exs, when it should have been .ex.

It is nice when the solution is simple. Please mark your own answer as "Solution" so this question can be put to rest.
